# Can a snowflake stream trigger a task without adding any schedule?

Tags: stream, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stream created in snowflake and a task which moves stream data into another table. I want the task to execute automatically every time there is new data in stream. How to automatically trigger the task when there is new data in stream?

Comment: It's not possible. You can run the task a bit more aggressively but otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks can only triggered on a schedule but you can have them run as often as every minute

If a run takes more than 1 minute, then the next task is delayed until 1 min after the previous task finishes

While it is not "on demand" a task running every minute should suffice for most situations. Of course it means a warehouse constantly running but the same would be true for an on demand service assuming new data arrives all the time. If data is irregular, you can add a stream has data check so the task does not run if there is no data: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_stream_has_data.html

Comment: Just to extend. Running task on demand is possible and it is in preview **[EXECUTE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-task.html)**

Comment: Lukasz you are correct. Should probably clarify that I meant you cannot automatically trigger a task, without a time schedule, based on whether the stream has data or not

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify stream cannot automatically trigger task to run and task has to run on schedule. Is there any way to automate the execute task command? Also an idea, can we use the execute task command inside a task?

Comment: Yes the stream cannot automatically trigger the task. The only way to automate would be using either a snowflake task as described above or some external code that monitors the stream but again this would probably be time based. I'm not sure about using execute task inside another task but wouldn't it make more sense to just use a task that triggers every minute and performs the operation you want?

Comment: Sure thanks. This was a big help.